# How to merge tuples returned by apply groupby in pandas of talib.BBANDS

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So let us say I have a dataframe, which is created like this and has 3 products A,B,C

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C'], 'x' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

Which you can print and see looks like below

```
   type x
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   B   3
3   B   4
4   C   5
5   C   6
```

Now I create a function called f, which returns tuple

```
def f(x):
    return x*2, x*3, x*4
```

And I apply this on the dataframe with groupby on type

```
df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x : f(x.x))
```

And now the result is a series of 3 array as below. But how do I merge it back to the dataframe correctly

```
type
A    ([2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8])
B    ([6, 8], [9, 12], [12, 16])
C    ([10, 12], [15, 18], [20, 24])
dtype: object
```

What I want to see is

```
type x a  b  c
A    1 2  3  4
A    2 4  6  8
B    3 6  9  12
B    4 8  12 16
C    5 10 15 20
C    6 12 18 24
```

EDITED:
Please note that I gave f function as a very simple example and it looks like why can't I directly create a new column with multiplication. But imagine a more complex function f that uses 3 columns and then generates tuples that it not straight forward column multiplication

That is why I asked this question

The real function in question is talib.BBANDS

Comment: I'm unsure what is the purpose of the `groupby` here? you seem to want to use your function  per row with your expected output, not related to the type? and if it is what you want, then there are better option than `apply`

Comment: Your example uses 'product' , not 'type'.

Comment: Corrected, as mentioned. please don't look at simple f and assume in all types of function f we can do simple column multiplication. I gave easy function as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming that in your real case**: the `groupby` is needed, your function takes several columns as input and return several columns as output, your function could return a dataframe:

```
def f(x):
    return pd.DataFrame({'a':x*2, 'b':x*3, 'c':x*4}, index=x.index)

# then assign directly or use join
df[['a','b','c']] = df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x : f(x.x))

print (df)
  type  x   a   b   c
0    A  1   2   3   4
1    A  2   4   6   8
2    B  3   6   9  12
3    B  4   8  12  16
4    C  5  10  15  20
5    C  6  12  18  24
```

Edit with the name of the function used `talib.BBANDS`, then I guess you can create a wrapper:

```
def f(x):
    upper, middle, lower = talib.BBANDS(x, ...) #enter the parameter you need
        return pd.DataFrame({'upper':upper, 'middle':middle, 'lower':lower }, 
                            index=x.index)
df[['upper','middle','lower']] = df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x : f(x.x))
```

Comment: Let us assume it is a library that is providing the function that your approach is not a generic approach

Comment: @Tahseen you can still wrap the said function of your library in another function that build the dataframe, or edit your question with the name of the function/library

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C'], 'x' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

newcol=df['x']**2
df['x**2']=newcol

df
```

output:
[image]

Comment: I know from where you are coming. I gave a simple example. But imagine if f is a complicated function that uses columns to generate tuples that cannot be generated by columns individually